# How do i avoid "cannot create native threads" while using ExecutorService?

Tags: java

I'm new to ExecutorService. Right now my scenario is "millions of data 365*24*7 is coming in"
I have some process to be done on data coming in using threads.

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThread();
es.execute(new ComputeDTask(data));
```

I'm sending data to ComputeDTask for some execution.

How efficient is it to create a `new ComputeDTask` each time data comes in?  That is, if data is received one million times, then a million ComputeDTask objects will be created.

Comment: Can we see the constructor for `ComputeDTask`?

Comment: Your question title seems to be completed unrelated to the content.  Are you asking about the cost of constructing lots of objects; or are you running into a "cannot create native threads" error?

Comment: while running the code program throws "cannot create native threads" after some particular period of executions.

Comment: my Constructor of ComputeDTask is only getting initialized by the value it sends.   public ComputeDTask(Object value) { this.value = value;}

Comment: how often are you calling `ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThread();` ???

Answer (score 2):

The overhead of creating a thread is about 100 micro-seconds. i.e. if you do less than 100 micro-seconds of work you will have more overhead than work done and you program can be slower that being single threaded.

The overhead of create a task to an existing Executor service is about 2 micro-seconds. i.e. if the task takes less than 2 micro-second you may have more overhead than real work done.

If you have CPU bound process, you need about the same number of threads as core to keep all the cores busy, while minimising overhead.

e.g. if you have 8 cores, I suggest you combine the work done so you have 8 threads with one task each *total*. You can have more tasks than this but you may find it take longer to process.

Of course you should shutdown your ExecutorService when you have finished with it.  The reason you don't see this done in all examples is that it can be a good idea to create **one** ExecutorService which is used for the life of the application.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you are creating a whole new `ExecutorService` for each task and never shutting them down. This of course results in the thread leak that you are observing. The proper way to use the `ExecutorService` is to create **a single instance** that manages the thread pool for you. The executors are very flexible and powerful in the way they manage the threads.

Comment: how could i get single instance of ExecutorService with many threads

Comment: [newCachedThreadPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool())

Answer (score 0):

On incoming data even create the task using `new ComputeDTask(data)` and then pass this to ThreadPool where you have let say 100 threads and then they can execute task with higher throughput.

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);

onGetData(){

     es.execute(new ComputeDTask(data));

 }
```